# PUG rendering of Chart

Tags: charts, pug

I am having issues trying to get this chartJS piechart to render in PUG. I would like to put the chartJS code in its own folder and then render it across a PUG template. Can explain what I am doing wrong or point me to some docs that may hep with this? As everyone will be able to see I am attempting to try this in a few different ways. I have placed screen shots in hopes that someone might be able to tell me the cleanest way to go about it, as well as simply getting it to render on the page. I have placed screenshots, please let me know if there is any further info that I could provide. Thanks for any help you can provide.

[app.JS File][1]

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path')
const app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'css')));


app.set('view engine', 'pug')
app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');


app.get ('/', (req, res) => {
res.render("dashboard", {title: "Home"})
})



app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('listening to PORT 3000')
})
```

[JavaScript Pug Code][2]

```
   $( document ).ready(function () {
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
})
```

[Main Dashboard Page][3]

```
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        title USRA-NASA-NAMS
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="./insight.css")
        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js")
        script(src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0')
        script(type="text/javascript" src='pieChart.js')    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer");

                chart.options.axisY = { prefix: "$", suffix: "K" };
                chart.options.title = { text: "Fruits sold in First & Second Quarter" };

                var series1 = { //dataSeries - first quarter
                    type: "column",
                    name: "First Quarter",
                    showInLegend: true
                };

                var series2 = { //dataSeries - second quarter
                    type: "column",
                    name: "Second Quarter",
                    showInLegend: true
                };

                chart.options.data = [];
                chart.options.data.push(series1);
                chart.options.data.push(series2);


                series1.dataPoints = [
                        { label: "banana", y: 58 },
                        { label: "orange", y: 69 },
                        { label: "apple", y: 80 },
                        { label: "mango", y: 74 },
                        { label: "grape", y: 64 }
                ];

                series2.dataPoints = [
                    { label: "banana", y: 63 },
                    { label: "orange", y: 73 },
                    { label: "apple", y: 88 },
                    { label: "mango", y: 77 },
                    { label: "grape", y: 60 }
                ];

                chart.render();
            }
```

[Pug Page with PieChart Code][4]

```
div(class="chart")        
            canvas(id="chartPic" width="400" height="400")
                script(src="chart.js")
                script. 
                    -window.onload = function() {
                    -var red="#{red}", green="#{green}", blue="#{blue}";
                    -var ctx = document.getElementById("chartPic").getContext('2d');
                        -var chart = new Chart(ctx,  {
                            -type: 'pie',
                            -data: {
                                -labels: ["red", "green", "blue"],
                                -datasets: [{
                                    -label: 'Number of votes',
                                    -data: [1, 1, 1],
                                    -backgroundColor: [red, green, blue],
                                    -borderColor: [green, blue, red],
                                    -borderWidth: 1
                                }],
                                },
                            -options: {
                                -title: { 
                                    -display: true,
                                    -text: "chart",
                                },
                                -legend: {
                                    -position: 'bottom'
                                },
                            }
                        });
                        };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include the code itself within the question. Screenshots of code aren't helpful.

Comment: I placed the code for you to see. I have changed it up a bit, was just trying to get the chart to represent at all, but cant see it  still. I would still like to create a JS file, and then represent that Chart in the PUG page, but not sure on that setup, as well as getting it to represent.

Comment: You shouldn't prefix javascript with `-` (dashes) when it's inside a `script.` block and intended to be run in the browser.

Comment: I did take those out and it fixed the problem. Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you please give an upvote to the question for the changes that were made, Sean. I an trying to get my rating back up to be able to ask questions. I am new to stackoverflow and was unaware, initially, of some of the policies. I am trying to change and update my questions to make the more suitable.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to remove the original issue. It makes things confusing for future users searching for answers. Questions should only be upvoted if they're useful and clear for future users.

Comment: I rolled it back to the previous version. My mistake. Again, if you would consider giving the question an upvote, since you did answer. It would be helpful